# Golang function as a parameter

Tags: go

I came across the following code to generate permutations of a given string.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    Perm([]rune("abc"), func(a []rune) {
        fmt.Println(string(a))
    })

}

func Perm(a []rune, f func([]rune)) {
    perm(a, f, 0)
}

func perm(a []rune, f func([]rune), i int) {
    if i > len(a) {
        f(a)
        return
    }
    perm(a, f, i+1)
    for j := i + 1; j < len(a); j++ {
        a[i], a[j] = a[j], a[i]
        perm(a, f, i+1)
        a[i], a[j] = a[j], a[i]
    }
}
```

I am having a hard time understanding how this program works. Especially the exit condition where a call is made to `f(a)` in func perm. Can someone explain what f(a) implies?

I tried printing `fmt.Println(f(a))` but got an error.

Go Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/FNijVw32iAy

Comment: f(a) converts a into a string and displays the result to the standard output. It is defined by fmt.Println(string(a)). As you can see the function perm is recursive as it calls itself and the if block is the end condition.

Comment: I made a small modification in `main()` that should clear things up: https://play.golang.org/p/qG9bALwC4G8

Comment: `f` is an argument to the `perm` function which itself takes arguments of type `[]rune` and returns nothing (like `void` in C-family languages), and `a` is an argument to the `perm` function of type `[]rune`, so `f(a)` makes sense. Since `f` returns nothing, `fmt.Println(f(a))` doesn't make sense and will error.

Comment: Please take the [Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/24), which covers all language basics including function values and closures.

Answer (score 1):

You have discovered a Closure!

[Also known as an anonymous function.](https://golangcode.com/anonymous-functions/)

It is basically a one off function that stays within its scope.

As for the printing not working, that's partly because of the anonymous nature, and partly because it has no return value to print. If you really wanted to get into it, you could try printing &f to generate a pointer so you have a value to print out.